# You have an error in your MySQL Syntax - in a simple Query

Tags: php

So I am trying to replicate a simple blogging system I made a month back, But the query no longer works on my new site
Here is the code

```
  <?php
function BlogPosts() {
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM "blog-posts" WHERE BlogDeleted = 0';
$value = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$value){
    die("<h1>QUERY ERROR IN BLOG_POSTS: </h1>". mysql_error());
}
while($n = mysql_fetch_array($value, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    ?>
    <h3><?php echo "{$n['BlogTitle']}"; ?></h3>
   <p><?php echo "{$n['BlogData']}"; ?></p>
   <b class="blog-user"><?php echo "entry by {$n['BlogUser']} on {$n['BlogTime']}"; ?></b>
<?php
}

} //END FUNCTION BlogPosts
?>
```

The full error is:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"blog-posts" WHERE BlogDeleted = 0' at line 1
EDIT: Fixed the error by adding the ` to blog-posts :)

Comment: You shouldn't have double quotes around "blog_posts": it's a table name, not a string literal. If you need to put anything around table or column names, it should be backticks (`)

Answer (score 2):

In your query,

```
"blog-posts"
```

should be

```
`blog-posts`
```

Normally, you can eschew the `` ` `` characters, but the hyphen in your table name requires them.

Comment: Oh my goodness! I feel like a derp!, It was adding the ` that fixed it for me haha thanks a bunch dude/dudette